# Python: have urllib skip failed connection

Tags: python, urllib

Using a Nokia N900 , I have a `urllib.urlopen` statement that I want to be skipped if the server is offline. (If it fails to connect > proceed to next line of code ) .

How should / could this be done in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) documentation, it will raise `IOError` if the connection can't be made.

```
try:
    urllib.urlopen(url)
except IOError:
    # exception handling goes here if you want it
    pass
else:
    DoSomethingUseful()
```

**Edit:** As unutbu pointed out, `urllib2` is more flexible. The Python documentation has a good [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html) on how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

```
try:
    urllib.urlopen("http://fgsfds.fgsfds")
except IOError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Python3, `urllib.request.urlopen` has a [timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) parameter. You could use it like this:

```
import urllib.request as request
try:
    response = request.urlopen('http://google.com',timeout = 0.001)
    print(response)
except request.URLError as err:
    print('got here')
    # urllib.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
```

`timeout` is measured in seconds. The ultra-short value above is just to demonstrate that it works. In real life you'd probably want to set it to a larger value, of course.

`urlopen` also raises a [`urllib.error.URLError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.URLError) (which is also accessible as `request.URLError`) if the url does not exist or if your network is down.

For Python2.6+, equivalent code can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/82928fce-f61f-49a2-9dd1-9fe3d1a8f59e/view-source).

Comment: need to use urllib not urllib2